# My sprite made with sprite kit doesn't move

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, sprite

I made a sprite using sprite kit in XCode and when i run the code evriwhere i click , nothing happen, here is the code of my Gamescene swift file :

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var entities = [GKEntity]()
var graphs = [String : GKGraph]()
var Firstplayer: SKSpriteNode?
private var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
private var label : SKLabelNode?
private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Setup player
    Firstplayer = self.childNode(withName: "Firstplayer") as? 
SKSpriteNode

}
```

Comment: why do you think it should move? where is the code responsible for the movement?

Comment: i followed this article to made it https://www.raywenderlich.com/1514-introduction-to-the-sprite-kit-scene-editor

Comment: How should the SKSpriteNode move?

Comment: as i read on the article linked it should moves by clicking on the screen , but this not happened, do you know a solution to move it?

Comment: you need to post your code relevant to "it should moves by clicking on the screen"